# Calling another function within a function - positioning the output

Tags: php, html, function

I have the following function:

```
public function createRatingButtons(){
        for($count=1;$count<=5;$count++){
            echo "<button onclick=''><b>$count</b></button> ";
        }
}
```

The above function simply creates 5 separate buttons, labelled 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5!

I am calling the above function below:

```
public function displayGrades($student,$unit){

        $studentID = $this->getStudentID($student);
        $unitID = $this->getUnitID($unit);
        $obj = new dbConfig();
        $obj->dbConnect();

        $sql="SELECT * FROM grading where studentID = '$studentID' && unitID = '$unitID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($obj->conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Independence</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Current Rating: " . $row['independence'] . "</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>" . $this->createRatingButtons() . "</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Participation</td>
                </tr>
                .
                .
                .
```

**PROBLEM:** It displays the buttons, but they do not appear in that column where I have called the function. The buttons appear above the table. I want them to appear in the same column where I am calling the function.

How do I fix this problem? Please can anyone help. Thank you in advance

Comment: From - public function createRatingButtons() {...} - return the button output.

Answer (score 1):

Your are echoing inside an echo, and this is not possible.

Maybe you should try to build a string of buttons, by doing this :

```
public function createRatingButtons(){
          $result = "";
          for($count=1;$count<=5;$count++){
              $result.="<button onclick=''><b>$count</b></button> ";
          }
          return $result;
}
```